# Concurrency and Passing by value in go

Tags: go, concurrency

I have a code snippet in go:

```
for _, u := range urls {
        done.Add(1)
        u2 := u
        go func() {
            defer done.Done()
            ConcurrentMutex(u2, fetcher, f)
        }()
        //go func(u string) {
        //  defer done.Done()
        //  ConcurrentMutex(u, fetcher, f)
        //}(u)
    }
```

In order for `ConcurrentMutex` to see different `u` values, one either needs to use a intermediate variable `u2` or use the code commented out. What if I simply do:

```
for _, u := range urls {
        done.Add(1)
        go func() {
            defer done.Done()
            ConcurrentMutex(u, fetcher, f)
        }()
    }
```

I am confused as to why the behavior of this will be different from the behavior of the code commented out. Go is passing by value, and when I pass `u` to `ConcurrentMutex`, shouldn't it just copy the value of the current `u` thus immune to the changes made on `u` later?

Comment: https://golang.org/doc/faq#closures_and_goroutines

Comment: Yes, arguments are always passed by value, but you don't know *when* the argument is evaluated, because it happens concurrently to the loop. For a loop this short it is very likely (but not guaranteed!) that all ConcurrentMutex calls happen after the loop is long finished.

Answer (score 2):

The moment `u` is passed to `ConcurrentMutex` a copy of it will be created and passed. However, when the goroutine passes the value of `u`, it may be different from the `u` value that was active when the goroutine started. That is, this execution is possible: the for-loop starts the goroutine with a `u` value, then the for-loop overwrites the `u` value with the next item in the sequence, and then the goroutine calls `ConcurrentMutex` with the new `u` value, skipping the previous `u` value.

Comment: Thank you and that makes sense. But why wouldn't this be a problem for the code commented out?

Comment: In the commented out code, a copy of `u` is passed to the function. Even if the `u` in for-loop changes, the copy in the function doesn't. This would've failed if you passed `&u` to a function getting a pointer.